# Date format issues in Calendar form field type Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am having an issues with Joomla `Calendar form field` type, Here is my code:

```
<field name="date" type="calendar" label="Date (*)"
            class="inputbox required" size="22"
            format="%Y-%m-%d"  labelclass="control-label" readonly="true" default="NOW"  
        />
```

What I am trying to do is to set the default value to current date in this field but it's shows the default value like this `2014-03-07 00:00:00` but I don't want to show time in this field, As you can see i have defined the format `"%Y-%m-%d"`, But don't know why it's show like that if some have any solution for it, Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

format (optional) is the date format to be used. This is in the format used by PHP to specify date string formats (see below). If no format argument is given, '%Y-%m-%d' is assumed (giving dates like '2008-04-16').

read [more](http://docs.joomla.org/Calendar_form_field_type)

If the above case not works then try below method.

In your XML

```
<field name="date" type="PubDateCalendar" label="Date (*)"
            class="inputbox required" size="22"
            format="%Y-%m-%d"  labelclass="control-label" readonly="true"  
        />
```

fields/pubdatecalendar.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.form.helper');
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('calendar');

class JFormFieldPubDateCalendar extends JFormFieldCalendar
{
    public $type = 'PubDateCalendar';
    protected function getInput()
    {

        $this->value = date('Y-m-d');

        return parent::getInput();
    }
}
?>
```

Hope its works..

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead... The difference between this code and @Jobin Jose solution above is where u call the parent. Looking in JFormFieldCalendar class show that is ovveride with its own formatting

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.form.helper');
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('calendar');

class JFormFieldCustomCalendar extends JFormFieldCalendar
{

    public $type = 'CustomCalendar';

    protected $defaultFormat = 'd-m-Y';

    /*
     * Un jour d'intervalle entre le debut et la fin
     */
    protected $interval = 'P1D';

    protected function getInput()
    {
        parent::getInput();

        // Build the attributes array.
        $attributes = array();

        empty($this->size)      ? null : $attributes['size'] = $this->size;
        empty($this->maxlength) ? null : $attributes['maxlength'] = $this->maxlength;
        empty($this->class)     ? null : $attributes['class'] = $this->class;
        !$this->readonly        ? null : $attributes['readonly'] = '';
        !$this->disabled        ? null : $attributes['disabled'] = '';
        empty($this->onchange)  ? null : $attributes['onchange'] = $this->onchange;
        empty($hint)            ? null : $attributes['placeholder'] = $hint;
        $this->autocomplete     ? null : $attributes['autocomplete'] = 'off';
        !$this->autofocus       ? null : $attributes['autofocus'] = '';

        if ($this->required) {
            $attributes['required'] = '';
            $attributes['aria-required'] = 'true';
        }

        $date = new DateTime("now");

        $format = $this->element['format'] ? (string) $this->element['format'] : $this->defaultFormat;
        $validFormat = preg_replace('/%/', '', $format);

        if ($this->element['default'] == 'start') {
            $this->value = $date->format($validFormat);
        } else if ($this->element['default'] == 'end') {
            $date->add(new DateInterval($this->interval));

            $this->value = $date->format($validFormat);
        }

        return JHtml::_('calendar', $this->value, $this->name, $this->id, $format, $attributes);
    }

}
```